# Any clue as to why my code has errors in it?

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, mplab-x

I used MPLAB X IDE (a software for microcontrollers) to compile my code, but for some reason it keeps saying that there are at least two errors (specifically in the area that is bolded). I tried looking, but I'm still not sure why that is, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xc.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <p18f4620.h>

#pragma config OSC = INTIO67
#pragma config WDT = OFF
#pragma config LVP = OFF
#pragma config BOREN = OFF
#define delay 5
// Prototype Area to place all the references to the routines used in the program
void Init_ADC(void);
unsigned char Get_Full_ADC(void);
void Flash_LED(unsigned char);
void main(void)
{
 unsigned int ADC_Result; // local variable to store the result
 Init_ADC(); // initialize the A2D converter
 TRISB =0x00; // make PORTB as all outputs
 while(1)
 {
 ADC_Result = Get_Full_ADC(); // call routine to measure the A2D port
 Flash_LED(ADC_Result); // call routine to flash the LED based on the delay
 // indicated by ADC_Result
 }
}
void Init_ADC(void)
{
 ADCON0=0x01; // select channel AN0, and turn on the A2D subsystem
 ADCON1=0x0E; // set pin 2 as analog signal, VDD-VSS as reference voltage
// and right justify the result
 ADCON2=0xA9; // Set the bit conversion time (TAD) and acquisition time
}
**unsigned int Get_Full_ADC(void)
{
int result;
 ADCON0bits.GO=1; // Start Conversion
 while(ADCON0bits.DONE==1); // Wait for conversion to be completed (DONE=0)
 result = (ADRESH * 0x100) + ADRESL; // Combine result of upper byte and lower byte into
 return result; // return the most significant 8- bits of the result.
}** 
void Flash_LED(unsigned int ADC_result)
{
unsigned int counter1, counter2;
 LATB = 0x0A; // output to PORTB the pattern 00001010
 // delay loop
 for (counter2=delay; counter2>0; --counter2)
 {
 for (counter1=ADC_result ; counter1>0; -- counter1);
 }
 LATB = 0x05 // output to PORTB the pattern 00000101
// delay loop
 for (counter2=delay; counter2>0; --counter2)
 {
 for (counter1=ADC_result ; counter1>0; -- counter1);
 }
}
```

Comment: You're asking us, as C# programmers, to check your C code? [Difference between C and C#](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-c-and-c-sharp/)

Comment: Note that meanwhile, someone else has edited the tag of your question from `c#` to `c`.

Comment: If you are talking about compiler errors, then please post these error messages (as text, not as an image).

Comment: "specifically in the area that is bolded" hmm... I don't see it.

Comment: As a minor I can see that you return an `int` but the prototype says: `unsigned int Get_Full_ADC(void)`

Comment: If you want help you had to show the error message.

Comment: Although using `**` for **bolding** will usually work when posting, this will not work inside text that is marked as code. Therefore, I suggest that you use some other means for marking your code, for example comments in CAPS, with empty lines above and below.

Comment: Stylistic note - some vertical whitespace, especially between function definitions, will go a long way towards making your code easier to read and debug.  The compiler doesn’t care, but it will help other people find your mistakes more quickly.  Also, I would suggest arranging your function definitions so that called functions are defined before their callers (at least in the same source file).  That way you don’t have to maintain a separate declaration for each function.  IOW, move `main` to the bottom of the source file, after the definitions of the other functions.

Comment: OT: For ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code (1 or 2 space indents will be lost when using variable width fonts)  Suggest each indent be 4 spaces.

Comment: regarding: `void main(void)`  Per the C standard, there are only two valid signatures for `main()`  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

Comment: regarding: `#include <xc.h>` This is not a standard C header file.  Where are you getting it from?  Home grown header files should be written via: `#include "xc.h"`  Note the use of `"` rather than `'<'`   and `'>'`

Comment: @user3629249 - the file xc.h is a system include for the microchip XC compiler and contains all of the processor variant descriptions and hardware register definitions.

Comment: @JohnBode - I concur with your stylistic notes.  I always tell new programmers that they should code as if the programmer having to maintain their code is a Hells Angels gang leader who knows where they live

Answer (score 7):

The function prototype (declaration) says

```
unsigned char Get_Full_ADC(void);
```

but its definition says

```
unsigned int Get_Full_ADC(void)
```

and also you have

```
int result;
...
return result;
```

So you never use the consistent type. The compiler will complain about the non-matching definition.

Comment: nice... I didn't see the `unsigned char`